How to disable the orange mic icon in the top panel for a specific app? (Gnome sound indicator issue)
I'm on Ubuntu 24.04 using Gnome. I installed PulseAudio and created a sink which has two loopbacks inside. One of which is my external microphone and the other is the internal system sound.
The problem is that the virtual stream - sink - is always in the recording state, even when I'm not recording anything using that. Its activity is displayed in recording tab of the PulseAudio. This causes the Gnome orange mic icon to be displayed on the panel, even when I'm not actually recording anything!
I need the sink to only be recording its loopbacks when other applications are recording, and to stop the loopback recording when PulseAudio is the only app using it(indicating that the sink is not needed anymore).
The goal is that this way, the orange mic icon is only displayed at times of "actually" recording something and not when the sink is "virtually" recording a loopback device.
For now, I create the sink manually whenever I need it, and remove it manually when I'm done with my recording!
My create_virtual_sink.sh script:
#!/bin/bash

# Load the modules and capture their indices
null_sink_index=$(pactl load-module module-null-sink sink_name=combined_input sink_properties=device.description=CombinedInput)
loopback1_index=$(pactl load-module module-loopback source=alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo sink=combined_input)
loopback2_index=$(pactl load-module module-loopback source=alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.2.monitor sink=combined_input)

# Store the indices in a file
echo "$null_sink_index" > /tmp/combined_input_module_indices
echo "$loopback1_index" >> /tmp/combined_input_module_indices
echo "$loopback2_index" >> /tmp/combined_input_module_indices

My remove_virtual_sink.sh script:
#!/bin/bash

# Read the module indices from the file
if [ -f /tmp/combined_input_module_indices ]; then
    indices=$(cat /tmp/combined_input_module_indices)
    
    for index in $indices; do
        pactl unload-module $index
    done
    
    # Remove the file after unloading the modules
    rm /tmp/combined_input_module_indices
else
    echo "No module indices file found."
fi


Update 3rd Dec 2024:
I learned how to develop gnome extensions to solve this annoying issue, i came up with a solution that fits your problem exactly, when you create loopback modules, they are created with a proper node.virtual = "true", so i developed an extension that can filter and ignore those source-outputs based on that property. Check it out:
https://github.com/moalhaddar/mic-indicator-visibilty-manager
You can install it by cloning the repo into the appropriate extensions folder:
git clone \
    https://github.com/moalhaddar/mic-indicator-visibilty-manager \
    $HOME/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/mic-indicator-visibility-manager@alhaddar.dev

Original:
I did not find the solution for the problem, but i found the root cause of it, and i do believe it can be solved with a custom gnome extension.
At the gnome-shell project, specifically under the file volume.js, the indicator checks for all the source-outputs, and if any source-output exist, then the annoying icon will be shown. Notice that how in the source code, it already filters and skips some apps:
     // skip gnome-volume-control and pavucontrol which appear
     // as recording because they show the input level
     let skippedApps = [
         'org.gnome.VolumeControl',
         'org.PulseAudio.pavucontrol',
     ];

In my case, i do have a virtual mic, whose input comes from a null sink, created by pactl modules, and that virtual mic is always shown in the output of pactl list source-outputs
Source Output #44
    Driver: PipeWire
    Owner Module: 536870914
    Client: n/a
    Source: 39
    Sample Specification: float32le 2ch 48000Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right
    Format: pcm, format.sample_format = "\"float32ne\""  format.rate = "48000"  format.channels = "2"  format.channel_map = "\"front-left,front-right\""
    Corked: yes
    Mute: no
    Volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    Buffer Latency: 0 usec
    Source Latency: 0 usec
    Resample method: PipeWire
    Properties:
        node.passive = "true"
        target.object = "VirtualMicSource"
        stream.capture.sink = "true"
        node.group = "virtual-source-536870914"
        pulse.module.id = "536870914"
        audio.channels = "2"
        audio.position = "[ FL, FR ]"
        device.description = "VirtualMic"
        node.link-group = "loopback-144583-11"
        node.virtual = "true"
        resample.prefill = "true"
        node.name = "input.VirtualMic"
        resample.disable = "true"
        media.name = "VirtualMic input"
        stream.is-live = "true"
        node.want-driver = "true"
        node.autoconnect = "true"
        media.class = "Stream/Input/Audio"
        adapt.follower.spa-node = ""
        object.register = "false"
        factory.id = "6"
        clock.quantum-limit = "8192"
        factory.mode = "merge"
        audio.adapt.follower = ""
        library.name = "audioconvert/libspa-audioconvert"
        client.id = "38"
        object.id = "44"
        object.serial = "44"
        module-stream-restore.id = "source-output-by-media-name:VirtualMic input"


That specific output is what is causing the mic icon to be shown. If only somehow we can also filter by some properties like node.virtual = "true", then the whole problem would be solved.
The issue is that i don't know how to start developing gnome extensions, so i'm keeping this here for the next person who comes across this issue.
